# In Jmeter how can I use MD5Hex assertion to verify the downloaded file?

Tags: http, jmeter, md5, jmeter-plugins

I want to verify the downloaded file's checksum,
I checked 'save response as MD5 hash" in the http request sampler,
and then I added a 'MD5hex assertion" with the md5hex as the result calculated by my Java application using the same file.
But the two checksum is not the same.
I wonder what's the reason. 
Is the response not the response body?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are misusing MD5hex assertion.

1. If you're using `Save response as MD5 hash` - you already have MD5 hash. In that case just use [Response Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion) to compare it with the expected hash.
2. If you're using [MD5Hex Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#MD5Hex_Assertion) - it automatically converts the response into MD5 hash. And if you already have `Save response as MD5 hash` - it becomes "MD5 from MD5" - that's why you see a mismatch. Just untick that box in HTTP Request sampler and everything should start working as expected.

See [How to Use JMeter Assertions in Three Easy Steps](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-assertions-3-easy-steps) article for more information on conditionally failing samplers using Assertions in your JMeter test.